# How ajax framework in D7 forms work?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am trying to understand and get the example working that was discussed here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax

I understand the form building function.

```
function ajax_example_simplest($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['changethis'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
      'one' => 'one',
      'two' => 'two',
      'three' => 'three',
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_simplest_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
    ),
    );

    // This entire form element will be replaced with an updated value.
    $form['replace_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("The default value will be changed"),
    '#description' => t("Say something about why you chose") . "'" .
    (!empty($form_state['values']['changethis'])
    ? $form_state['values']['changethis'] : t("Not changed yet")) . "'",
    '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_textfield_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    return $form;
}
```

What I don't understand is what is happening in ajax callback function.

```
function ajax_example_simplest_callback($form, $form_state) {
    // The form has already been submitted and updated. We can return the replaced
    // item as it is.
    return $form['replace_textfield'];
}
```

The same form field is returned. I thought we can change the value or something for the form item $form['replace_textfield'] through ajax callback function. Can some one pls help me to explain this part?

Answer (score 2):

All ajax logic placed in construct form function (ajax_example_simplest), ajax callback just return part of form (replace_textfield) or [ajax commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7). Its Drupal architecture. This form can be validate and altering.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That cleared a part of it. If i have to change button text on ajax callback when clicked on, what should i be returning from ajax callback function?

Comment: $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-submit', 'val', array('New button text'));
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

Answer (score 1):

Please spend some time with the AJAX Example in the [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples). This is also available on [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example.module/7), but it's best just to get the code and experiment with it. It tries to explain exactly what's going on and best practices with it. Also, http://randyfay.com/ajax.